# Unable to make PUT request using Volley Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to use volley to make a PUT request to a service.
But i am getting :
"BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for "

The request works fine if I use Postman and other REST clients.

Please help !!

Here's my code :

```
private void update(String url) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", user.getEmail());
            params.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
            params.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Basic a2lkX1MxZVZIRlpROmJiMzIxODAwMzI1MTRlMGZiNTk5ZDc1NDU4MTRhNDgx");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Please make a [mcve].